# Leaflet Delete polyline between 2 markers

Tags: leaflet, marker, polyline, angular-leaflet-directive

How I can delete the polyline line between 2 specific marker.
I have many polyline connected with many marker . But i want to delete any sspecific line on double click .

How Can I do that ?

I am using leaflet to draw the polyline.
[image]

here suppose I want to delete the polyline between marker 3 and 4 on double click. what will be procedure to do that.

Thank you.

I tried something like this but its not working , Can anybody please help me where is the mistakes ?

```
//polyline delete on double click 

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.polycoords.length; i++) {
        var polyline = $scope.polycoords[i];
        $scope.polycoords[i].on('click', function (e) {
        console.log("sdd",polyline._leaflet_id);
         for (var j = 0; j < $scope.polycoords.length; j++) {
            if($scope.polycoords[i]._leaflet_id = $scope.polycoords[j]._leaflet_id){
                  console.log($scope.polycoords[j])
                  var polyline = $scope.polycoords[j];
                      map.removeLayer(polyline);
               }


           }


     });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
polyline.on('dblclick', function (e) {
    map.removeLayer(this);
});
```

**Edit**
This is going to work because based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810267/marker-with-polyline-while-dragging-the-marker-using-leaflet) here on SO, I know that you create a different polyline for each line. But for anyone else that creates a single polyline with all the coordinates together, this solution will delete the whole polyline, not just a part of it.

Comment: It deleting only the last line.

Comment: You should put this solution after the creation of each polyline (if I remember correctly, inside that double loop that you have). You should post your sample code here too so others can understand.

Comment: [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810267/marker-with-polyline-while-dragging-the-marker-using-leaflet) Here the sample code which I used to drag polyline with marker

Comment: Where are you attaching the event handler? It should be right after the creation of the polyline. Please provide the updated code with what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you so much . It's working now. Thank you for your time.