# How to use leaflet draghandler in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, this

I'm using Leafletjs to display a map on my website. I'm now starting to use Vuejs in it, but I'm getting errors because suddenly `this` refers to the Vuejs instance.

Consider the following function which works great outside of Vuejs (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520112/1650012)):

```
var marker_a = new L.Marker(a, {draggable: true}).addTo(map);

marker_a.on('dragstart', dragStartHandler);

function dragStartHandler (e) {
    var latlngs = polyline.getLatLngs(),
    var latlng = this.getLatLng();
    for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {
        if (latlng.equals(latlngs[i])) {
            this.polylineLatlng = i;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use it in Vuejs:

```
methods: {
    dragStartHandler: function (e) {
        var latlngs = this.polyline.getLatLngs();
        var latlng = this.getLatLng();latlng
        for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {
            if (latlng.equals(latlngs[i])) {
                this.polylineLatlng = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that instead of `polyline.getLatLngs()` I now use `this.polyline.getLatLngs()` because I now load `polyline` from the Vuejs context. That works great. Unfortunately `this.getLatLng()` gives me an error saying `this.getLatLng is not a function`. That makes sense because I never defined `getLatLng()` in Vuejs. I'm not sure how to point it to the Leaflet context though.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: In your outside of vue.js code, What does this `var latlng = this.getLatLng();` line of code is doing, can you please elaborate.

Comment: And If you want to get rid of all these mess, I recommend you to use this [Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-leaflet). I have used it for my project. It is best wrapper for leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the event argument that Leaflet passes to your `dragStartHandler` listener (your `e` argument): it should have a [`target`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#event-target) member that references the Leaflet layer that dispatched the event, in your case `marker_a`.

```
methods: {
  dragStartHandler: function (e) {
    var latlng = e.target.getLatLng();
  }
}
```